# No permission to run docker-entrypoint.sh although it is set in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Even though I'm setting the proper permissions in a Dockerfile, `docker-compose up` throws an error:

> Attaching to lab-track-raport-app-db-1, lab-track-raport-app-web-1

> Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./docker-entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

My Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Set workdir
WORKDIR /code

# Copy project files
COPY . /code/

# Install dependencies
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Add permissions for the entrypoint file
RUN chmod +x "./docker-entrypoint.sh"

# debug
RUN ls -la .

# maybe it's overwritten when mounting volume? set permissions again
CMD ["chmod", "+x", "./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    depends_on:
      - db
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Waiting"
./wait-for-it.sh "db:3306"

echo "Apply database migrations"
python manage.py migrate

echo "Seed database"
python manage.py loaddata seed.json

echo "Running the app"
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: I recommend reading up on [the interaction between `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

Comment: You should delete your `CMD` statement. It's passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` as parameters, but you don't do anything with it. Even if it was used - which it isn't - It's missing `.sh`

Comment: Thanks. However, it's not about missing .sh. Still not working. I will read the links posted above.

Comment: I know it's not about the missing `.sh`. LIke I said, the statement does absolutely nothing except add confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copy your code into the `/code` directory, but then at runtime you also map your current directory onto `/code` which then 'hides' the /code directory in the image and replaces it with the current directory from your host machine.

Remove the volume mapping, so the container can use the `/code` directory in the image

```
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mariadb
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
    depends_on:
      - db
```